# Optimize calculations in this query?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-optimization

What's the best way to optimize this query?

```
$tripsNearLocation = mysqli_query($con, 
   "SELECT * FROM (
       SELECT *
       , ( 3959 * acos( cos(" . $latRad . ") 
         * cos( radians( startingLatitude ) ) 
         * cos( radians( startingLongitude ) 
         - (" . $longRad . ") ) 
         + sin(" . $latRad . ") 
         * sin( radians( startingLatitude ) ) ) ) 
         AS distance FROM trips
      ) as query 
   WHERE distance < 10 
   ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 10;");
```

With 50,000 rows it takes it a second or two to finish. Should I add a different query that eliminates all rows that aren't even in the "close range" of the coordinates inputted then calculate the remaining rows? Say if the latitude coordinate inputted is 67, eliminate all rows with latitude coordinate that isn't from 65-69.

Or add a "state column" where it removes all rows from calculations if they aren't in the same state?

Or just deal with the 2 seconds of calculations? I'm worried the database may contain more that 100,000 rows and it will take to long to excute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plan A:  For 100K rows, you might get away with just narrowing down by latitude.  That is,

- calculate the degrees latitude that corresponds to "10" units of distance
- Have INDEX(startingLatitude)
- Add to the WHERE clause to limit it to startingLatitude plus/minus "10".  Perhaps your example is `AND startingLatitude BETWEEN 65 AND 69`.

If you are thinking about using INDEX(lat, lng), it is not as simple.  See if Lat is good enough.

Plan B:  Next choice will involve lat and lng, plus a subquery.  And version 5.6 would be beneficial.  It's something like this (after including `INDEX(lat, lng, id)`):

```
SELECT ... FROM (
    SELECT id FROM tbl
        WHERE lat BETWEEN... 
          AND lng BETWEEN... ) x
    JOIN tbl USING (id)
    WHERE ...;
```

For various reasons, Plan B is only slightly better than Plan A.

Plan C:  If you are going to need millions of rows, you will need [my pizza parlor algorithm](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng).  This involves a Stored Procedure to repeatedly probe, looking for enough rows.  It also involves `PARTITION`ing to get a crude 2D index.

Plans A and B are `O(sqrt(N))`; Plan C is `O(1)`.  That is, for Plans A and B, if you quadruple the number of rows, you double the time taken.  Plan C does not get slower.  (It sounded like your code is `O(N)` -- double the rows = double the time.)

Comment: I'm thinking I could narrow down using plan a by latitude and longitude. Would that work just as well?

Comment: It's not that simple because the optimizer will look at only one range, not two.  I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Answer is mostly right but completely ignores spatial indexing which is available as standard in most mysql implementations and will give a much faster and more accurate result.

Comment: @symcbean - Please provide an answer using `SPATIAL`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I ended up solving it incase people need to reference this in the future.

```
$tripsNearLocation = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM (
SELECT *, (3959 * acos(cos(" . $latRad . ") * cos(radians(startingLatitude)) 
* cos(radians(startingLongitude) - (" . $longRad . ")) + sin(" . $latRad . ") 
* sin(radians(startingLatitude)))) AS distance FROM (
SELECT * FROM trips_test WHERE startingLatitude BETWEEN " .
($locationLatitude - 1) . " AND " . ($locationLatitude + 1) . ") as query1) 
as query2 WHERE distance < 10 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 10;");
```

Although I will accept Rick James' answer as he helped me get to this solution.